# Edge detection in images

Tags: computer-vision

I am working on edge detectors: Canny, Sobel, Prewitt, and Roberts. These edge detectors work with conventional kernels to compute the edge. The kernel values are multiplied with the pixel values of an image, and then we compute an average value.

Suppose my average pixel value is 12, while the old value (of the original image) was 10. I know how these edge detectors work, but how do I determine using the gradient value that an edge is present in the image or not? I am pretty confused with these matrix calculations, specifically about angles of edges.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  it's hard to tell what specifically you are asking.  Can you identify a more specific question?  You might want to pick a single edge detector and ask about it.  What specifically is your confusion/uncertainty?  It sounds like this question is "edge detectors; I don't understand", but without telling us what you don't understand, it's hard to know how to help.  The more you can give us to work with, the more likely that we can give you a useful answer.

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uihBwtPIBxM) i am using sobel edge detection to find edges in images see video example. sobel find edges using 2 kernel matrix in x and y direction and angles of edges.it just put the values of gradient in images how can we determine its is a edge or not?i cant understand this step in detail cant find a good article in detail version.

Comment: Please try harder formulating your question. Your syntax was pretty hard to understand. Check my rephrasing to make sure that I understood you correctly.